# Old Launch Screen and black display after iOS app update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, launch-screen, launchimage

I made an iOS app with Xcode and Swift. In v2, I also updated Launch Screen and Launch Images.

I first installed v1 of my app from the App Store. When the new, v2, was available from the App Store I updated my app on my devices. That's an iPhone 5s with the newest iOS and an iPhone 7 Plus with the newest iOS.

After updating my app on the iPhone 7 Plus it still showed up the old Launch Screen. Restart didn't help. I had to delete and reinstall the app to get the new Launch Screen shown up.

On iPhone 5s I didn't get any Launch Screen or Launch Image, I got a black screen for the time the Launch Screen shot get shown. I deleted and reinstalled the app. That didn't help. I also had to restart the device after reinstalling the app to get the right v2 Launch Screen.

Why that strange behavior? What can I do? *I cannot ask my users to reinstall the app and restart the devices.*

Comment: do you delete old app build before installing new. ?

Comment: @JagveerSingh How do you mean this?

Comment: delete app from phone and instal

Comment: I think I made it this way. 1. Delete v1 completely from my device. 2. Install v2 from Xcode to test it. 3. Overwrite v2 by v1 (old app) from the App store to have the real update scenario as the user also has. 4. Update v1 with v2 from the App Store (when it's approved by Apple and Ready for Sale).

Comment: Should I have delete the test v2 from Xcode before installing v1 (old app) from App Store and later update this to v2 from App Store?

Answer (score 0):

- After updating the Launch image, delete the application `cache` which is stored in `DerivedData` folder.
- If you are using `xib` or `storyboard` for displaying LaunchScreen move the images into an `asset` catalog, rather than using the `png` filenames.

Comment: I always do `Product>Clean` and `Product>Clean Build Folder…`. Is that the same as manually delete the Cache in DerivedData? I'm using `Launch Screen.storyboard` and LaunchImage in `Assets.xcassets`. Is that the right way?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that works for me was to add the images outside Images.xcassets folder. After modified this and rebuild the app, it worked expected.